# What are the benefits of creating an "updatable view" vs a straight insert?

Tags: postgresql, sql-view

As it mentions in the PostgreSQL manual

> Currently, views are read only: the system will not allow an insert,
>   update, or delete on a view. You can get the effect of an updatable
>   view by creating rules that rewrite inserts, etc. on the view into
>   appropriate actions on other tables.

What are the benefits to creating an updatable view using rules vs a straight insert/update operation? Are there any hidden "gotchas" that I would need to be aware of?

--Update--

It seems that 9.3 will include updatable views:

http://www.depesz.com/2012/12/11/waiting-for-9-3-support-automatically-updatable-views/

> The next release of PostgreSQL is planned to be the 9.3 release. A tentative schedule for this version has a release in the third quarter of 2013.

This is still a ways away but it looks like this may make life a touch easier for any who need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can have a **stable interface** to a client and still change the structure of underlying tables as long as you edit the rules on the view accordingly. I happened to use this in the past, when I had to remove a table and didn't want to wake a difficult client, so I provided a view as drop in and the client never noticed the change.
- In a multi-user environment you can **manage privileges** on one view more easily than privileges on multiple tables.
- Another benefit is in the last word of your quote: *tables* - plural. This way, a client can send ***one* query** and you can change multiple underlying tables. You can achieve this with triggers, too, mostly.

Other than that, it's regularly simpler to operate with triggers.

Comment: @RobertH Note that in newer PostgreSQL versions you can use `INSTEAD` triggers on views. They can be preferable to rules (they're easier to get right and easier to debug) and offer another alternative. (+1)

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks for the alternative, I'll be sure to check it out.